# DialogFragment not attached to activity and returning null

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity, android-dialogfragment

I'm attempting to have my DialogFragment pop up in my EditItem activity after a click. It immediately crashes and says that the:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.groceryapp, PID: 13885
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.groceryapp.EditItem.imageClicked(EditItem.java:86)
        at com.example.groceryapp.EditItem.access$000(EditItem.java:25)
        at com.example.groceryapp.EditItem$1.onClick(EditItem.java:68)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

EditItem.java

```
public class EditItem extends Activity {
    Context appContext;
    String itemName;
    LinearLayout imageHolder;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    Bitmap imageBitmap;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_item);

        imageHolder = findViewById(R.id.itemImageInput);
        imageHolder.setOnClickListener(imageHolderListener);
        imageHolder.setOnLongClickListener(imageHolderLongListener);
        itemName =  getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.itemNameInput);
        textView.setText(itemName);
    }

    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
    }

    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
    }


    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
    }


    private View.OnClickListener imageHolderListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            imageClicked();
        }
    };

    private View.OnLongClickListener imageHolderLongListener = new View.OnLongClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view){ imageLongClicked();
            return false;
        }
    };

    private void imageClicked(){
       // Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //Intent.createChooser(takePictureIntent, "Take or retrieve picture");
        try{

            ImagePickerFragment dialog = new ImagePickerFragment();

            dialog.show( dialog.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"ImagePickerFragment");
          /*  CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .start(this);*/
            //startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
            Log.wtf("TAG", "Something isn't working correctly");
        }
    }

    private void imageLongClicked(){
        //delete image
        imageHolder.removeAllViews();
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK);
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imageViewCreater(imageBitmap);
    }
//add imageview programmatically
    private void imageViewCreater(Bitmap bm){
        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        int length = dpToPx();
        image.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500,500));

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                bm, length, length, false);
        image.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
        imageHolder.addView(image);
    }

    public int dpToPx() {
        int dp=166;
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    }

}
```

ImageFragmentPicker.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

public class ImagePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public ImagePickerFragment(){

    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_picker_dialog,container,false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

From my understanding it seems like my Dialog is only attached to a Context and not an Activity. I'm a bit befuddled as to how to get this changed around. My best guess is that there is something wrong with the constructor but I can't exactly state what.

Comment: You are calling `getSupportFragmentManager()` from a class derived from Activity so why do you need the `dialog.getActivity()`? Just call `getSupportFragmentManager()` directly.

Comment: @JimRhodes it tells me "Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager' in 'EditItem'" whenever I try to use the method. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Sorry, `getSupportFragmentManager()` is a member of `FragmentActivity`. Perhaps you can extend from`androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`.